# Create a generic List<SelectListItem> function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have two DbSets:

```
public DbSet<Reports.Models.Application> Application { get; set; }
public DbSet<Reports.Models.Category> Category { get; set; }
```

In the controller, I'm creating two `List<SelectListItem>`s:

```
var applications = _context.Application
    .Select(listItem => new SelectListItem 
      { 
        Value = listItem.ID, 
        Text = listItem.Name 
      }
    ).ToList();

var categories = _context.Category
    .Select(listItem => new SelectListItem
      {
        Value = listItem.ID, 
        Text = listItem.Name
      }
    ).ToList();
```

I'd like to refactor this into a single, private method:

```
private List<SelectListItem> SelectList<T>(bool blankListItem = false)
{
    var selectListItems = _context.<T>  <------ doesn't compile
        .Select(listItem => new SelectListItem
          {
            Value = listItem.ID,
            Text = listItem.Name
          }
        ).ToList();

    if (blankListItem) 
        selectListItems.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = $"Choose {{T.ToString}}", Value = "" }));

    return selectListItems;
}
```

And call it twice:

```
var applications = SelectList<Application>(); 
var categories = SelectList<Category>();
```

or

```
var applications = SelectList<Application>(true); // add "choose" 
var categories = SelectList<Category>(true); // add "choose"
```

What's the right way to define the `_context.<T>` part?  Perhaps this should be an extension method of the `DbSet` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have your dbsets inherit a base class. which would be representing the generic type `T`.

Something like;

```
public class BaseClassForDbSets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Application : BaseClassForDbSets
{
}

public class Category : BaseClassForDbSets
{
}
```

and then your private method;

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataSource, bool blankListItem = false) where T : BaseClassForDbSets
    {
        var selectListItems = dataSource 
              .Select(listItem => new SelectListItem
              {
                  Value = listItem.Id.ToString(),
                  Text = listItem.Name
              }
              ).ToList();

        if (blankListItem)
            selectListItems.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = $"Choose {nameof(T)}", Value = "" }));

        return selectListItems;
    }
```

Then you would call it like;

```
var applicationCollection = GetSelectList(_context.Application);
var categoryCollection = GetSelectList(_context.Category);
```

Do note - not tested

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses a different approach, but same result.

Start with an interface:

```
public interface IBaseSelectItem
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Have your entities (Application and Category) implement the interface:

```
public partial class Category : IBaseSelectItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create an extension on DbSet:

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> AsSelectList<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, bool useChooseValueOption) where T : class, IBaseSelectItem
{
    var selectList = dbSet
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id.ToString(), Text = c.Name })
        .ToList();

    if (useChooseValueOption)
        selectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "-Choose Value-" });

    return selectList;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
var categoriesSelectList = _dbContext.Categories.AsSelectList();
```

Comment: I like the approach.  Could the extension method support a Boolean to include the 'Choose value' option?

Comment: sure, you could can add a bool parameter (see my edit). or you can add a SelectListItem parameter if you want to. or even a List<SelectListItem> parameter if you want to have multiple extra items